# searching for members in wordpress

Tags: php, members

I have custom fields setup in S2MemberPro, lets say they are these:

memberid
phone
referredby

I want to search the custom fields if searching those fields, and if searching the normal fields like these:

first_name
last_name
email
ID

those are the normal fields that are in Wordpress, so I assume they are in two different locations.

So using PHP, in my search query, what would I search for?

I tried this:

```
$_searchedWhat = $_REQUEST['field'];
$_searchedFor = $_REQUEST['search'];
echo "Searching the " . $_searchedWhat . " fields for " . $_searchedFor . "...<br />
<br />";
$tusers = get_users( array( "search" => $_searchedFor ) );

// also tried it this way:
$tusers = get_users( array( "$_searchedWhat" => $_searchedFor ) );

// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $tusers as $user ) {
    echo "Id: " . $user->ID . " - Member Username: " . $user->user_login . " - Member Name: " . $user->first_name . " - Member Lastname: " . $user->last_name . " - email: " . $user->user_email . '<br />';
}
```

those did not work, except if I searched for email. If I searched for email, the first one worked.

So, is there a way to search both tables where the custom_fields are stored for all the members with that data in the field I'm searching?

What I echoed there, was just for the testing of it. I'll have it output something useful that I'm doing this for.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this plugin is using user_meta table. Your query should looks like this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => $_searchedWhat,
    'meta_value' => $_searchedFor
);

$users = get_users($args);
```

For more informations look into documentation: [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users#Parameters)

EDIT: Unfortunately, that plugin is storing all data into one field, so you cannot query users by single field. You should use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) in posts or [create own meta boxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) with inputs that will store each field separately.

Comment: I went and looked, it looks like they are in these field:
wpth_s2member_custom_fields
all have the same meta_key field but the data is in that wierd dotNotation that wp uses: 
a:10:{s:10:"first_name";s:3:"Jimmy";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Carson";s:11:"referredby";s:3:"100";s:5:"phone";s:14:"(405) 463-6182";s:14:"street_address";s:11:"1611 E. 7th";s:15:"street_address2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:8:"Boise";s:5:"state";s:2:"ID";s:3:"zip";s:5:"00000";s:7:"country";s:13:"United States";}

The search I did for: "city" and searched for "Boise" did not result in any records, so what what would work?

Comment: This notation is creating, when array is saved into meta table (PHP `serialize` function). I will change my answer to fit into this.